# What's the recommended way to define URL patterns and versioning for backend services and API definitions in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager

We are facing a problem when including our Java application services in WSO2 API Manager. Our typical backend applications runs on Tomcat and has a context path, e.g. (/customer-manager). Its Spring controllers define endpoints with this format: `/api/VERSION/resource`, e.g: `/api/v1/customers`, `/api/v2/customers`, etc.

Thus, our calls to the backend look like this: `http://localhost:8080/customer-manager/api/v1/customer`. Our autogenerated swagger documentation publishes the REST path information as `/customer-manager/api/v1/customers`.

Now, when creating an API definition in WSO2 we are forced to specify a context path, and a version (/customer-manager, v1) and this information is prepended to the API calls, so our WSO2 API invocations are like this:

`https://WSO2_HOST:WSO2_PORT/customer-manager/v1/customer-manager/api/v1/customers`.

As you can see, **the context path and the version are duplicated**.

So this raises a few questions:

- We could make our backend applications get rid of their own context path and deploy them as the only application in Tomcat (ROOT.war). **Is it expected that the backend applicacions DON'T have a context path?**
- In order not to duplicate the version, we could also remove it from our backend app, now having prettier URLs: `https://WSO2_HOST:WSO2_PORT/customer-manager/v1/api/customers`. But, in the case of a **backend application supporting two simultaneous versions of an API, how could we distinguish which backend endpoint should process them?** Notice with the previous approach we had two backend mappings `/api/v1/customers` and `/api/v2/customers` and it was explicit which one would process the versioned call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having context and version details in the backend URL is normal and it is not always possible to remove them from the backend. By looking at the question I assume you are trying to publish an API using a swagger file. Maybe you have to check why the swagger definition sets "/customer-manager/api/v1/customers" as the Rest path(resource). If you can update the backend to set the "/customer-manager/api/" as the base path and "customer" as the resource the repeating context paths can be avoided.

If that is the case you can create the API with the following options.

```
Name: customer-manager
Context: /customer-manager/api
Version: v1
Resource: customers (This will be identified through Swagger definition)
Backend URL: http://localhost:8080/customer-manager/api/v1
```

If changing swagger definition is not possible, you can just create the API definition in API Manager by defining the resource as I mentioned above instead of using the Swagger based option. You can use the **Design a new REST API** option in this case.